# EntityFramework and IDataErrorInfo : Default implementation for string Error

Tags: .net, entity-framework, idataerrorinfo

I have just been wondering if this (default) implementation for IDataErrorInfo.Error is good or evil in some ways:

```
public string Error
{
    get 
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        foreach( PropertyInfo propertyInfo in GetType().GetProperties( System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Public ) )
        {
            String propertyError = this[ propertyInfo.Name ];

            if ( String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace( propertyError) == false )
            {
                if( sb.Length > 0 )
                {
                    sb.Append( Environment.NewLine );
                }

                sb.Append( String.Format( CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "[{0}] - {1} ({2}"
                                            , propertyInfo.Name
                                            , propertyError
                                            , propertyInfo.GetValue( this ) ) );
            }
        }

        return sb.ToString();
    }
}
```

Besides of course the potential problem with GetValue, the missing check for NotMapped and the potential performance issue that can be mitigated by caching the properties in a static list.

Thanks

Mario

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You pointed out the main drawbacks that makes the design fairly evil...

Properties should not have much processing code, as the msdn guidelines suggests : [Property Usage Guidelines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bzwdh01d).

In this case, I suggests you to :

1. Store the errors in a private string list (or whatever collection or dictionary that may fit well).
2. Fill the list from the indexer property (the one that implement `IDataErrorInfo`)

This way, the `Error` property will just have to concat the errors.